# Confusion about a proof about subgroups of dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

This [article](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) shows that every subgroup of $D_n = \langle r, s \rangle$ is cyclic or dihedral.

> **Theorem 3.1.** Every subgroup of $D_n = \langle r, s \rangle$ is cyclic or dihedral. A complete listing of the subgroups is as follows:
>
> (1) $\langle r^d \rangle$, where $d | n$, with index $2d$;
>
> (2) $\langle r^d, r^{i}s \rangle$, where $d | n$ and $0 \le i \le d − 1$, with index $d$.
>
> Every subgroup of $D_n$ occurs exactly once in this listing.

The proof is as follows:

> It is left to the reader to check $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ separately. We now assume $n \ge 3$.
>
> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $D_n$. The composite homomorphism $H \hookrightarrow D_n \to D_n/\langle r \rangle$ to a group of order 2 is either trivial or onto. ***Its kernel is $H \cap \langle r \rangle$***.
>
> $\ldots$

Why is the kernel $H \cap \langle r \rangle$? I failed to prove this by showing that the kernel cannot contain reflections such as $r^{i}s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G $ be a group and $N\triangleleft G$. Consider the natural homomorphism  $\pi:G\to G/N $ given by $g\mapsto gN $.

**Claim**: $\ker (\pi)=N $.

**Proof**: Let $n\in N $. Then $\pi (n)=nN=N $. So $N\subseteq \ker (\pi)$.
Let $g\in \ker (\pi) $. Then $gN=N $ or $g\in N $. So $\ker (\pi)\subseteq N $. Hence $\ker (\pi)=N\;■$

Let $H$ be a subgroup of  $G$ and consider the restricted homomorphism  $\pi|_{H}:H\to G/N$ given by  $h\mapsto hN $. Clearly, $\ker (\pi|_{H})=H\cap \ker (\pi)=H\cap N$.

---

Note that $\pi|_{H}$ is same as $H \overset {\iota}{\hookrightarrow} G \overset {\pi}{\to} G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of the quotient map is $ \langle r \rangle$ and the kernel of the overall map is the preimage of this under the inclusion map, which is $H\cap \langle r \rangle$.